# Compiling a SFML project directly with the sources and CMake

Tags: cmake, sfml

I want to compile a SFML projet directly with the SFML sources.

I'm using CLion, it's an IDE who use CMakeLists as project proprety file 
(he use CMake himself)

Here is my CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SFML/CMakeLists.txt)

project(R-Type)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -static -static-libgcc -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")

set(SOURCE_FILES
    Client/src/main.cpp)

include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Client/Include ")

add_executable(R-Type ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

As you can see , i'm trying to call the CMakeLists who is bundled with the SFML sources, but its doesnt work ..

Error log (after copying manually the header SFML file in my project )

```
C:/Users/roman/Documents/CLionProjects/R-Type/Client/src/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale' 
C:/Users/roman/Documents/CLionProjects/R-Type/Client/src/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf9VideoModeC1Ejjj' 
C:/Users/roman/Documents/CLionProjects/R-Type/Client/src/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6WindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE'
C:/Users/roman/Documents/CLionProjects/R-Type/Client/src/main.cpp:20: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6Window5closeEv'
C:/Users/roman/Documents/CLionProjects/R-Type/Client/src/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6Window9pollEventERNS_5EventE'
C:/Users/roman/Documents/CLionProjects/R-Type/Client/src/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK2sf6Window6isOpenEv'
C:/Users/roman/Documents/CLionProjects/R-Type/Client/src/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6WindowD1Ev'
C:/Users/roman/Documents/CLionProjects/R-Type/Client/src/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6WindowD1Ev'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As you can see the compilor can't link with SFML despite the call of SFML CMakeList

Comment: *I'm trying to call the CMakeLists who is bundled with the SFML sources* -> that's really not how it works. You should probably read up on how to **link** libraries with CMake.

Comment: @Hiura So how can i do that ?

Comment: Read about CMake in general, especially find_package and target_link_library. Despite your question, the compiler (actually the linker) does not even try to link to the SFML library.

Comment: @usr1234567 Yes, i read a little bit more about SFML sources and the cmakelists provides with actually compile the sources to a ".a" or ".dll" files.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `CMake` to build and install SFML onto your system.  In your application that consumes SFML, you should use the appropriate [cmake modules provided by SFML](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/tree/master/cmake/Modules) to locate the individual libraries that you need.  (SFML is not a single library it is a group of libraries: EGL, FLAC, etc.)

The find modules provided with SFML set appropriate cmake variables that you use in `target_link_libraries` for your executable.

If you look at [test_driven.pdf](https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2014/blob/master/files/test_driven/test_driven.pdf) from my C++ Now! 2014 [presentation on Test-Driven Development](https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2014/tree/master/files/test_driven), I walk through an example of using cmake to locate Boost.Test with `find_package`.  You would use `find_package` similarly to locate the SFML packages described by the SFML modules.

Of course, none of this is going to make sense to you without investing some time in learning how cmake works.  In order to properly use your build system (cmake), you need to understand your build system and how it works.

What you have done in your example is to include the SFML `CMakeLists.txt` directly in your `CMakeLists.txt` for your project, which is not how this is intended to be used.  I'm not even sure if you can get it to work that way.